# dropdown is close when i click outside and whene i click in the <li> is not closed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

This is my useEffect function for if i click outside of the liste it will be closed

First when i click in the <li> the list is showed but when i click again in to <li> it doesn't closed

[enter image description her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrPXs.png) That my list

```
let menuRef1 = useRef()
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (e) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (!menuRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setListLong(true)
      // @ts-ignore
    }
    if (menuRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setListLong(false)
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", handler)
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handler)
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Please do not create [duplicates of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928844/my-card-icons-are-not-the-same-position-when-the-paragraph-is-bigger-or-small).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My card icons are not the same position when the paragraph is bigger or small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928844/my-card-icons-are-not-the-same-position-when-the-paragraph-is-bigger-or-small)